# puppeteer-sharp how to wait requests

Tags: c#, .net, puppeteer-sharp

how to wait request to be done before clicking on btn in puppeteer-sharp ?

what I am trying to do is:

1.click on btn ( to make ajax request on website ) 
2.wait request to be done 
3.click on submit btn

what I am doing now is:

1.click on btn ( to make ajax request on website  ) `await page.ClickAsync("#id")` 
2.wait for some time ( `await page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(2000);` ) 
3.click on submit btn

Comment: What does your code look like now?  What does it do now?

Comment: I edited the question: now I am waiting for some time but this is not accurate

Comment: @MarkSameh add your code here, how others help without knowing the issue properly

Comment: What does clicking the button actually do? Does it perform an ajax request? Perform a navigation? The solution will depend on what the button does.

Comment: I edited it when click on the btn it doesn't navigate, it sends a request to the backend I want to wait until this request is done then do next action

Comment: What defines done? `WaitForSelectorAsync` can be used to detect changes in the `DOM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the method I was looking for to wait for the request to be done : 
`await page.WaitForResponseAsync()`